# Radio button condition in html

Tags: javascript, html

I have created two radio button in html...

If the user select the Option 1 it should go to fill.jsp page

or

If user select Option 2 it should go to renew.jsp page...

How can i give the condition...

```
    <input type="radio" name="op1" value="option 1"/>option 1<br>

    <input type="radio" name="op1" value="option 2"/>option 2<br>

    <input type="submit" value="START" name="START" />

</center>

</body>
```

Comment: Condition in what? Do you have a form that is submitting this to a server, or do you just want a javascript redirect somewhere? As a sidenote, the center tag is deprecated, and if you give the radio's the same name they will actually work as radio buttons.

Comment: I want javascript to redirect...If the user click the option 1 it have redirect to fill.jsp page...or If user click the option 2 it have redirect to renew.jsp page

Comment: radio buttons should have the same name, and only differ in their values

Comment: His radio buttons do have the same name.

Comment: `<input type="radio" name="op1" value="option 1" onclick="window.location.href = 'someotherpage.html'" />`

Comment: @nFinIt_loop that was edited after I posted

Comment: Thank You all i got it... 

I just give like this...

<input type="radio" name="POLICY" value="NEW POLICY" onclick="window.location.href = 'index.jsp'"/> NEW POLICY <br>
        
<input type="radio" name="POLICY" value="POLICY RENEWAL" onclick="window.location.href = 'renewal.jsp'"/> RENEWAL <br>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case if there are more than two radio buttons you can use something like the following(No. of radio buttons is same as you provided in the below HTML shown.But Javascript that i provided will work for any number of radio buttons):

**HTML**

```
<form>
    <input type="radio" name="op1" value="fill.jsp"/>option 1<br/>
    <input type="radio" name="op1" value="renew.jsp"/>option 2<br/>
    <input type="button" value="START" name="START" onclick="jsubmit();" />
</form>
```

**Javascript**

```
function jsubmit(){
    var radio = document.getElementsByName('op1');
    for(i=0;i<radio.length;i++)
    {
        if(radio[i].checked){
        window.location.href = radio[i].value;
        }
    }
}
```

### [Demo using four radio buttons](http://jsfiddle.net/7P7Cn/5/)

Answer (score 0):

If using jQuery:

HTML

```
<input type="radio" name="op1" value="option 1"/>option 1<br>

<input type="radio" name="op1" value="option 2"/>option 2<br>

<input id="submit" type="submit" value="START" name="START" />
```

JS

```
$("#submit").on("click", function(){
    var radioSelected = $("input[name=op1]").val();
    if(radioSelected == "option 1"){
        window.location.href = "fill.jsp";
    }else if(radioSelected == "option 2"){
        window.location.href = "renew.jsp";
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $('input[name=op1]').on('change',function(){
      if($(this).val() == 'option 1'){
        window.location.href = 'fill.jsp';
      }else{
         window.location.href = 'renew.jsp';
      }
    });
```

Comment: Add some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

name= is your group name, so having op1, and opt2, with only one radio in each would leave both selected giving the posted data.  Using a simple demo_form.asp" method="get" to test...

> Input was received as:
>   op1=option+1&op2=option+2&START=START

Changing the groupname to the same group like this produces a single selected option

```
<input type="radio" name="option_groupname" value="option 1">fill<br>
<input type="radio" name="option_groupname" value="option 2">renew<br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

When selecting Option 1 (fill)

> Input was received as:
>   option_groupname=option+1

And then when selecting option 2 (Renew)

> Input was received as:
>   option_groupname=option+2